# Spark mllib : how to convert string categorical features into int for Rating to accept

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I want to build a recommendation application using spark mllib and the ALS algorithm in collaborative filtering technique. My data set has the user and product features in string form like :

```
[{"user":"StringName1", "product":"StringProduct1", "rating":1},
 {"user":"StringName2", "product":"StringProduct2", "rating":2},
 {"user":"StringName1", "product":"StringProduct2", "rating":3},..]
```

But the [Rating](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/Rating.html) method seems to accept only int values for both user and product features. Does that mean I will have to build a separate dictionary to map each string to an int? My dataset will have duplicate entries for both user and product.Is there a built-in solution for this in the mllib library itself?

Thanks and any help appreciated!

Edit: No, this is not a duplicate as the answer in that question doesn't seem to fit my scenario. `spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating` library doesn't seem to support String values for `user` or `item`. I need this support.

Comment: what is the form or your dataset? is it `RDD[(String, String, Float)]`?

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao yes.

Comment: @void Answer by JohnTitusJungao should be sufficient. You don't expect anything else here, right?

Comment: @zero323 No, it's good for me. Just wanted to know if ml module had a solution which will accept String values for user or item, as you marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: I actually was wrong. I thought there is `specialized` ALS version for strings but it is only `Int` and `Long`. You can use `StringIndexer` and pipelines though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try. Assuming that `data: RDD[(String, String, Float)]`

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating

val data = sc.parallelize(Array(("StringName1", "StringProduct1", 1.0), ("StringName2", "StringProduct2", 2.0), ("StringName3", "StringProduct3", 3.0)))

//get distinct names and products and create maps from them
val names = data.map(_._1).distinct.sortBy(x => x).zipWithIndex.collectAsMap
val products = data.map(_._2).distinct.sortBy(x => x).zipWithIndex.collectAsMap

//convert to Rating format
val data_rating = data.map(r => Rating(names(r._1).toInt, products(r._2).toInt, r._3))
```

That should do it. Basically, you just create a mapping from string to long and then convert long to int.

Comment: But after doing this, how do I do the predictions after training? Let's say I have a tuple of `(names, products)` to predict the rating. How do I map the names to the corresponding index in the training set?

Comment: if you have `new_data: RDD[(String, String)]`, you have to create `val new_data_rating = new_data.map(r =>(names(r._1).toInt, products(r._2).toInt))` then feed that into model.predict.

Comment: One final question. So, what if in my `new_data_rating`, there is a name that was not present in the training set. This is supposed to be handled by the ALS algorithm, but here I will have to handle it?

Comment: That's a good question. Basically, what the ALS algorithm does is factor the matrix formed from `data` using the rows and columns it has already seen. When you perform predict on say a new `(name, product)` pair, it will search for the factor of the name and factor of the product then compute for the corresponding rating.

Comment: @void If user or product are not present in training data then ALS cannot handle this.

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao how to do this in pySpark?